# c3p0 says - "java.lang.Exception: DEBUG ONLY: Overdue resource check-out stack trace" on starting a hibernate transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions, c3p0

Recently, my tomcat started hanging up. The requests were never replied. I figured out that it was due to connections never being returned to the connection pool.

I have used c3p0 with hibernate and the database is mysql 5.5

In order to debug the connection leaks, I added the following properties in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
```

After adding them, in the logs it says :

```
[2013-10-12 23:40:22.487] [ INFO] BasicResourcePool.removeResource:1392 - A checked-out resource is overdue, and will be destroyed: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1f0c0dd
[2013-10-12 23:40:22.487] [ INFO] BasicResourcePool.removeResource:1395 - Logging the stack trace by which the overdue resource was checked-out.
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG ONLY: Overdue resource check-out stack trace.
```

Pointing to `at dao.DAOBasicInfo.getBean(DAOBasicInfo.java:69)`

```
public static Basicinfo getBean(Integer iduser) {
        Basicinfo u = null;
        Session sess = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();   //line 69
            Query q = sess.createQuery("from Basicinfo where iduser=" + iduser);
            u = (Basicinfo) q.uniqueResult();
            if (u == null) {
                u = new Basicinfo();
                u.setIduser(iduser);
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }
        return u;
    }
```

I cross checked and [Mysql says it supports transactions with InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)

Because of the above error, I'm having un-returned connections and then they pile up making the app unresponsive.

Please let me know what's wrong in starting a transaction and even I'm using finally and there's no exception thrown.

Comment: hi. so, unusually, there is no obvious Connection leak in the code from which the unreturned Connections come. is your application hanging directly inside this code block? a thing to try would be to set unreturnedConnectionTimeout back to zero and have your JVM dump stack traces during the hang. if it's a Connection leak, you'll see client Threads waiting in c3p0's awaitAvailable(). but you may see that your Threads are hung somewhere within this code, which would give you a clue about what you need to fix.

Comment: thanks @SteveWaldman - I added rollback and it seemed to the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions to debug it

- As Steve mentioned in comments. Try to see what happens when you remove the unreturnedConnectionTimeout option.
- May be your queries are taking too long. Try to log some performance stats on your code and see how much time your query is taking. May be you need to tune your query. and for short term you can also increase the unreturnedConnectionTimeout to be more than the response time on your queries.
- Also try transaction timeout option in hibernate. May be set  tx.setTimeout(20) and play with the timeout numbers and see if some queries timeout.
- You may also want to use some profiling tool. Try [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) in case your Java version is supported on it. Otherwise (if on linux or mac) you may want to try [Java Debugging commands](http://www.fromdev.com/2008/12/debugging-java-on-unixlinux-my-favorite.html) on older version of java. Some of those commands are also available from JDK.

**Small improvements on the code**

- Not sure if it will really fix your issue however you may want to add rollback for transaction in exception block. Added another try catch for tx.close to avoid another exception.
- Also added a null check for session close. You may already know that one condition when finally may not completely execute  - if another exception is thrown in finally block. Currently it may not be applicable in your code however in case you add more than one line in finally block make sure any exceptions are covered so next line can execute.
- One more suggestion is to reduce the scope of transaction itself. Looking at the code it seems you may need the transaction only in case a uid is not found. How about limiting the transaction code inside if(u==null) block. Not sure if helps but you need not have transaction for read.

Below is my sample code

```
    public static Basicinfo getBean(Integer iduser) {
    Basicinfo u = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    Session sess = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {

        Query q = sess.createQuery("from Basicinfo where iduser=" + iduser);
        u = (Basicinfo) q.uniqueResult();
        if (u == null) {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();   //line 69
            u = new Basicinfo();
            u.setIduser(iduser);
            tx.commit();
        }           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if(tx != null) {
            try {
             tx.rollback();
            } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace;}
        }
    } finally {
        if(sess!=null) {
         sess.close();
        }
    }
    return u;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons this error comes up is when you don't make sure to

> transaction.commit();

*not an answer to this question, but someone who forgot to commit will also land on this page after googling the error*