# What means this hibernate message "A checked-out resource is overdue"?

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

When I run my java application I get the following error after few minutes running ok:

```
Jan 30, 2014 9:25:09 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool removeResource
INFO: A checked-out resource is overdue, and will be destroyed: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@7e687f77
Jan 30, 2014 9:25:09 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool removeResource
INFO: Logging the stack trace by which the overdue resource was checked-out.
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE: Overdue resource check-out stack trace.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:555)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3927)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2476)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:988)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:807)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:781)
```

I just want to know **what means** this hibernate message *"A checked-out resource is overdue"*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337638/c3p0-says-java-lang-exception-debug-only-overdue-resource-check-out-stack-t

Comment: Presumably you are setting `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` on your connection pool. You might want to read this: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout

Comment: echoing samlewis, you've git `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` both set, which is useful for debugging Connection leaks. (but `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` is slow in production!) if your `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` is set to a sufficiently long value, then you probably have a Connection leak, and the stack trace shows the codepath that opened the Connection which has never been closed. in addition to samlewis' link, see also http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients (inside the same document)